# how to implement message level security in web service

Tags: web-services, message-level-security

I have to write client for webservice which is using private key to encrypt the xml data and send it over wire.

I am unable to find anything useful which help me to build my understanding over same.
Most probably I have to do this with spring ws security.

--> my server is using wso2 framework for the same.

Kindly help me out with ur experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use rampart (ws security module comes with WSO2 framework) at the client side as well.

You need to set the policy at the client side and invoke the client using the relevant modules please have a look here[1].

If your server uses WSO2 platform there is an option to generate the client using the admin console. If you have engaged the security to the service generated client has those policies.
Take a look at the rampart[2] samples as well.

[1] http://wso2.org/library/3190

[2] http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/rampart/

Comment: Thanks for the immediate reply. Any other option you think i have? do you have idea weather we can write our client Using JAX-WS our spring any other module?